# JQuery.contents not working using jsdom

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, web-crawler, jsdom

This code does work in the browser, but in Node.js (using JSDom + Crawler), i returns `undefined`

```
$('div').find('.class').contents()[0].wholeText
```

Any idea on how to solve this?

BTW, when I try to stringify this in nodejs, it returns the error `Circular defintion`

The full code:

```
var Crawler = require("crawler").Crawler;
var data = {}
var c = new Crawler({
  maxConnections: 10,
  skipDuplicates: true,
  // This will be called for each crawled page
  callback: function(error, result, $) {

    // $ is a jQuery instance scoped to the server-side DOM of the page
    $("#link > ul > li > a").each(function(index, a) {
      c.queue(a.href);
    });
    $("[id^=enfr]").each(function(index, a){
      var fr = $(this).find('.FrWrd strong').html().replace(/<(?:.|\n)*?>/gm, '')
      var to = $(this).find('.ToWrd').contents()[0]
      console.log(fr + '\t\t\t\t\t' + to)
    })
  }
});

// Queue just one URL, with default callback
c.queue("http://www.wordreference.com/enfr/0");
```

Comment: Is `.queue` jquery `.queue()` ? Thanks

Comment: @guest271314 nope. It is part of the Crawler

Comment: Not tried `node.js` , `crawler` , `jsdom` . Tried `.contents()` without `[0]` ? , or `$(this).find('.ToWrd')[0].outerHTML` ?

Answer (score 0):

OK Finally I resolved it by using the "stock" DOM library:

```
  var to = $(this).find('.ToWrd').get(0).firstChild.nodeValue
```